# Error ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException when try to get price of study lamps on pepperfy.com

Tags: selenium

I try to implement same logic to get the offer price for study lamps from pepperfry.com but I am getting ArrayIndexBoudn exception. Please find below code :

**Code**

```
package com.Ecommerce;



import java.util.List;



import org.openqa.selenium.By;

import org.openqa.selenium.Keys;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;

import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;



public class PageLaunch {



public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

// TODO Auto-generated method stub

System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C://Users//484834//Downloads//chromedriver.exe");

WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

driver.get("https://www.pepperfry.com");

driver.manage().window().maximize();

Thread.sleep(8000);

driver.switchTo().frame("notification-frame-22a3358b6");

driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("span.wewidgeticon.we_close.icon-large")).click();  // Close first pop Up

System.out.println("************Closed First Pop UP************");

driver.switchTo().defaultContent();

Thread.sleep(8000);

//driver.switchTo().alert().dismiss();

//driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='signinupPopupBox']/a")).click();

//System.out.println("************Closed Second Pop UP************");



driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@itemprop='query-input']")).sendKeys("study lamp");

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@itemprop='query-input']")).sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);

System.out.println("************Study Lamps are Searched************");

Thread.sleep(8000);

driver.switchTo().frame("webklipper-publisher-widget-container-notification-frame");

driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("span.wewidgeticon.we_close.icon-large")).click();

System.out.println("************Closed Third Pop UP************");

driver.switchTo().defaultContent();

List<WebElement> productPrices = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("span.clip-offr-price "));

System.out.println("Size is "+productPrices.size());

for(int i=0;i<productPrices.size();i++)

{

//System.out.println(productPrices);

String[] price = productPrices.get(i).getText().split(".");

//Rs.1,239

String p = price[1].replace(",", "");

int actualPrice =Integer.parseInt(p);

System.out.println("Actual Price of Study lamp is "+actualPrice);

}
}
}
```

**OutPut**

> Starting ChromeDriver 77.0.3865.40
>   (f484704e052e0b556f8030b65b953dce96503217-refs/branch-heads/3865@{#442})
>   on port 5562
>
> Only local connections are allowed.
>
> Please protect ports used by ChromeDriver and related test frameworks
>   to prevent access by malicious code.
>
> Nov 18, 2019 5:04:27 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake
>   createSession
>
> INFO: Detected dialect: W3C
>
> ************Closed First Pop UP************
>
> ************Study Lamps are Searched************
>
> ************Closed Third Pop UP************
>
> Size is 48
>
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
>
> at com.Ecommerce.PageLaunch.main(PageLaunch.java:54)

Answer (score 3):

It's a special character. You need to split as below.

```
String[] price = productPrices.get(i).getText().split("\\.");
```

I ran your code and it is working with the above code changes.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this because the price String array is empty on line 81 and on line 85 you are trying to access index[1] of price.

```
String[] price = productPrices.get(i).getText().split(".");
```

You need to put it inside for loop so that you will get the value of (i)